# Need help fixing error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python

I am new to python, am doing a small assignment, and have hit a bit of a snag. I would like to know how to append to the bottom empty line of a file that I have.

The code already prints out what is in the '.txt' and 'cnt' comes out as the next line with no text in it.

```
#Open the desired file
f = open("Testing.txt", "r")

#Read out lines of the file and number them
line = f.readline()
cnt = 1
while line:
    print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
    line = f.readline()
    cnt += 1
print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, newline))
f.close()

#Append new line to bottom of file
f = open("Computers.cfg", "a")
f.writelines(newline)[cnt]
f.close()
```

If the file reads something like

```
Hello
I am
here
```

I want to add "now" to the bottom line, so that it reads

```
Hello
I am
here
now
```

Am I going about this properly or is there a better or cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You haven't defined `newline`.

Comment: I didn't add in the full code, 'newline' is just a string of words that someone inputs. Right now it is: 'with a hat'

Comment: Do you want to put the text from `Testing.txt` plus the `newline` into the `Computers.cfg`?

Comment: Yes, exactly right! The files have the same text in them, I just want to edit one and not the other. For all intent and purposes 'Testing.txt' could be in both spots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, I've simplified things a fair bit. See if this works for you.

```
#Open the desired file
f = open("Testing.txt", "r")
text = f.read()

if text[-1] != '\n':
    newline = '\n'+newline

f.close()

#Append new line to bottom of file
n = open("Computers.cfg", "w")
n.write(text+newline)
n.close()
```

Comment: So that worked for you? That's great. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 0):

“TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable” is one of the Python errors does not provide a clear answer for new developers.

What this means is that you are trying to use the subscript (or indexing) operator `[]` on an object that does not support this operation.

The reason it is referring to `NoneType` is that the response from `File.writelines()` is `None`.

Putting all of this together you are attempting to index into None on the line `f.writelines(newline)[cnt]`.

Changing this line to `f.write("\nnow")` would resolve the issue ("\n" is the shorthard for newline).